# how to fix error in BeautifulSoup IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this website, but I still found this error each time, although there is text in the `span` tag, the code show error:

```
line 49, in <module>
    beds.append(bed[i].text)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want scrape All beds text in each advertisement page

```
# 1 lists
    district_Name = []
    property_size = []
    property_price = []
    links = []
    dates = []
    beds = []
    paths = []
    page_num = 0
    
    # 2 the link of website
    while True:
    
            result = requests.get(f"https://www.bayut.sa/en/riyadh-region/villas-for-sale/page-{page_num}/")
            src = result.content
    
            # 4 create soup
            soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    
    
    
            if page_num > 288:
                break
    
            # 5 titles we need: districtName, property Age, size, rooms, price
            districtName = soup.findAll("div", {"aria-label": "Location"})
            size = soup.findAll("span", {"aria-label": "Area"})
            price = soup.findAll("span",{"aria-label": "Price"})
            listing_link = soup.findAll("a", {"aria-label": "Listing link"})
            bed = soup.findAll("span", {"aria-label": "Beds"}, {"class": "b6a29bc0"})
            path = soup.findAll("span", {"aria-label": "Beds"}, {"class": "b6a29bc0"})
    
    
    
            main_url= 'https://www.bayut.sa'
    
            # 6 for loop to get text and append it to a list
            for i in range(len(districtName)):
                district_Name.append(districtName[i].text)
                links.append(main_url+listing_link[i].attrs["href"])
                property_size.append(size[i].text)
                property_price.append(price[i].text)
                beds.append(bed[i].text)
                paths.append(path[i].text)
    
    
            for link in (links):
                result = requests.get(link)
                src = result.content
                soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
                date = soup.find("span", {"aria-label":"Reactivated date"})
                dates.append(date.text)
    
            page_num+=1
```

Comment: You forgot to ask your question. Please (re)read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In case if there is a information e.g. bed missing your list will have different length, so you have to handle this cases.

```
'bed' : e.text if (e := item.find("span", {"aria-label": "Beds"}, {"class": "b6a29bc0"})) else None,
```

In my opinion, you should rethink the way you process the data, move away from the abundance of lists and focus on a more structured approach.

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []
page_num = 0

while True:
    result = requests.get(f"https://www.bayut.sa/en/riyadh-region/villas-for-sale/page-{page_num}/")
    src = result.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

    main_url= 'https://www.bayut.sa'

    for item in soup.select('li[aria-label="Listing"]'):
        data.append({
            'districtName' : item.find("div", {"aria-label": "Location"}).text,
            'size' : item.find("span", {"aria-label": "Area"}).text,
            'price' : item.find("span",{"aria-label": "Price"}).text,
            'listing_link' : main_url+item.find("a", {"aria-label": "Listing link"}).attrs["href"],
            'bed' : e.text if (e := item.find("span", {"aria-label": "Beds"}, {"class": "b6a29bc0"})) else None,
            'path' : item.find("span", {"aria-label": "Beds"}, {"class": "b6a29bc0"}).text
        })

    #....
    #....

    page_num+=1
    if page_num > 3:
                break
data
```

#### Output

```
[{'districtName': 'Al Rimal, East Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '300 Sq. M.', 'price': '1,500,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488480.html', 'bed': '6', 'path': '6'}, {'districtName': 'Al Yarmuk, East Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '285 Sq. M.', 'price': '1,300,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488484.html', 'bed': '4', 'path': '4'}, {'districtName': 'Al Khaleej, East Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '280 Sq. M.', 'price': '1,750,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488611.html', 'bed': '4', 'path': '4'}, {'districtName': 'Al Arid, North Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '420 Sq. M.', 'price': '3,000,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488444.html', 'bed': '4', 'path': '4'}, {'districtName': 'Ishbiliyah, East Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '900 Sq. M.', 'price': '4,000,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488471.html', 'bed': '4', 'path': '4'}, {'districtName': 'Al Malqa, North Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '600 Sq. M.', 'price': '7,100,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488439.html', 'bed': '5', 'path': '5'}, {'districtName': 'Al Narjis, North Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '312 Sq. M.', 'price': '2,600,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488396.html', 'bed': '4', 'path': '4'}, {'districtName': 'Al Malqa, North Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '720 Sq. M.', 'price': '8,700,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488443.html', 'bed': '5', 'path': '5'}, {'districtName': 'Al Khaleej, East Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '450 Sq. M.', 'price': '2,500,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488472.html', 'bed': '5', 'path': '5'}, {'districtName': 'Al Malqa, North Riyadh, Riyadh, Riyadh Region', 'size': '375 Sq. M.', 'price': '4,800,000', 'listing_link': 'https://www.bayut.sa/en/property/details-87488526.html', 'bed': '5', 'path': '5'},...]
```