# IndexError when appending output form web scraping within a for loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, index-error

I am trying to web scrape glassdoor, but I get an IndexError. My code has the following form:

```
html = requests.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/germany-data-science-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,7_IN96_KO8,20_IP1.htm?includeNoSalaryJobs=true', timeout = 5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')


# extracts the hyperlinks in each jobposting
link = []
for i in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'd-flex flex-column pl-sm css-1buaf54 job-search-key-1mn3dn8 e1rrn5ka0'):
    li = 'https://www.glassdoor.com' + i.a['href']
    link.append(li)

# extracts the job descriptions by creating a new soup from each link extracted above
description = []
for links in link:
    page = requests.get(links, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    for job in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'desc css-58vpdc ecgq1xb5')[0]:
        try:
            description.append(job.text.strip())
        except:
            description.append(None)
```

I want to extract the job description of all jobs, which are within `div` or `p` tags within the `div` tag of `('div', class_ = 'desc css-58vpdc ecgq1xb5')`. When running the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aedan\PycharmProjects\Data_Science_Job_Openings\main.py", line 47, in <module>
    for job in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'desc css-58vpdc ecgq1xb5')[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I used try and except to append "nothing" to solve the error, as shown above, but it didn't work. I also used `html.parser` instead of `lxml`. I also tried the solution of this post [how to fix error in BeautifulSoup IndexError: list index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333644/how-to-fix-error-in-beautifulsoup-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range), but I was not able to structure my code in that way to try it.

Comment: If there are no divs with that class, `find_all()` will return an empty list. You need to check for that before you try to index it with `[0]`. And if you only want the first match, use `find()` instead of `find_all()`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar. I thought the ``find_all()`` would give me everything that is within the class instead of giving me all the classes that match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, use `find()` or 'select_one()' if you like to select only one element or check that there is an element in your `ResultSet`.

But also, if you use `find()` try to check the availability of the element you searched for and handle this case.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
html = requests.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/germany-data-science-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,7_IN96_KO8,20_IP1.htm?includeNoSalaryJobs=true', timeout = 5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')

data =[]

for url in ['https://www.glassdoor.com' + a.get('href') for a in soup.select('li[data-id] a:first-of-type')]:
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
    data.append({
        'url':url,
        'desc':None if not soup.find('div', {'id':'JobDescriptionContainer'}) else soup.find('div', {'id':'JobDescriptionContainer'}).get_text(strip=True)
    })

data
```

Comment: Thank you very much @HedgeHog, it worked. I just have one follow up question regarding the argument in ``soup.select('li[data-id] a:first-of-type')]``. Could you explain what exactly this means? I understand that all the ``a`` tags are within a ``li`` tag, but I don't understand the rest.

Comment: Happy to help, the rest is only to be more specific in selection https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors  /  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors Try to avoid classes, use more static identifier or HTML structure

Comment: Perfect, thanks again. I will have a deeper look into the documentation you've sent!